# Picklist Sorting Alphabetical Order

Tags: picklist

On a vf page i have a picklist.
Values are-- ABC, XYZ, PQR and Other. 
can we have the list in Alphabetical order with "Other" the last option.

I have sorted Picklist when defining it.
But i want other to always be last options in picklist

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sort the list before adding "other", then add "other".

```
SelectOption[] options = new SelectOption[0];

for(...) {
    options.add(new SelectOption(value, label));
}

options.sort();
options.add(new SelectOption('-- other --', 'Other'));
return options;
```

Or, you can embed "other" directly into the list, forcing it to be last:

```
<apex:selectList ...>
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!myOptions}"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="-- other --" itemLabel="Other"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

Comment: How if i am using an input Field. Because this code i have to write it for each and every picklist on vf page. I have 10 picklist on the page.. All picklist has other options

Comment: I used the 1st set of code for the picklist values comng from apex class.. It worked charms